# Can I install a Windows 8 on a not Genuine Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8

I am currently using a not genuine windows 7,  I'm planning on buying a original windows 8 installer.. 
Can I upgrade my current version of windows to 8 and be a genuine copy?.. What do i have to do?..

Comment: Pretty sure it's the product key that determines if Windows is genuine or not... not the installer that's used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Windows will upgrade a non-genuine install, but will ask you for the Windows 8 during the upgrade.

Comment: okay thanks, and another question. when i get my original copy of windows 8 can i install it in my pc? which is a not genuine copy?